# Am I closing excel file properly when using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel export

Tags: c#, asp.net, office-interop, export-to-excel

I am using the following [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to export data to Excel.

I have modified this code so that I can export & save it to an Excel file but I am not sure if I am closing the excel file properly and my second question is if I do it that way, does that need to handle any Garbage collection etc..
,
Please advise if I don't have it correct or if there is a better way of doing the same.

```
  static void DisplayInExcel(DataSet ds)
    {
        var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        // Make the object visible.
        excelApp.Visible = true;

        // Create a new, empty workbook and add it to the collection returned  
        // by property Workbooks. The new workbook becomes the active workbook. 
        // Add has an optional parameter for specifying a praticular template.  
        // Because no argument is sent in this example, Add creates a new workbook. 
        excelApp.Workbooks.Add();

        // This example uses a single workSheet. 
       // Excel._Worksheet workSheet = excelApp.ActiveSheet;

        // Earlier versions of C# require explicit casting. 
        Excel._Worksheet workSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet; 

        // Establish column headings in cells A1 and B1.
        workSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "Date";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "C"] = "Title";
        workSheet.Cells[1, "D"] = "Details";

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
        var rowIndex = 2; // 1 = header row
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
           // rowCount++;
            workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, "B"] = row["Date"];
            workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, "C"] = row["Title"];
            workSheet.Cells[rowIndex, "D"] = row["Description"];
            rowIndex++;
        }


        workSheet.Range["A1", "D" + rowIndex + ""].AutoFormat(Excel.XlRangeAutoFormat.xlRangeAutoFormatColor2);

        //Coloumn 1
        workSheet.Range["A:A"].Cells.Font.Bold = true;
        workSheet.Range["A:A"].ColumnWidth = 10;
        workSheet.Range["A:A"].HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        //Column 2
        workSheet.Range["B:B"].ColumnWidth = 14;
        workSheet.Range["B:B"].HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter;
        //workSheet.Range["A1", "A" + rowIndex + ""].Cells.Font.Bold = true;


        ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Columns[3]).AutoFit();
        ((Excel.Range)workSheet.Columns[4]).AutoFit();

        string fileName = "Product_Excel.xls";
        excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
        workSheet.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../"+fileName));


        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        excelApp.Quit();

    }
```

Comment: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: @JohnSaunders, very Well noted. It seems i have to use traditional way of doing things. I agree with you as just started have trouble with it on webserver also..

Comment: There are other ways to do it. Look at EPPPlus, for instance.

Comment: I managed to use ClosedXML for this purpose & it is working fine... but with one problem it doesn't support HTML based contents only RichText. I will lookinto EPPPlus to see if it has support for HTML etc..

Answer (score 0):

Here's my closing statements.

Make sure you call this after you catch all exceptions:

```
try
{
  //Use spreadsheet here.
  DisplayInExcel(ds)
}
catch
{
  //Process errors
}
Close();
```

And here's the closing code:

```
public void Close()
{
    try
    {
        if (_workBook == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _workBook.Save();
        _workBook.Close(false, FILENAME, null);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_workBook);
        _excel.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(_excel);
        _workBook = null;
        _excel = null;
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        Logger("All done!");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger("Error in cleanup: " + e.ToString());
    }
}
```